# Turning a goat?

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, matches

[image]

This is a goat made up of 5 sticks. You have to move (change position) any one stick of them such that its head turns to the right side (above the right leg).

Notice currently its head is on the left side and above the left leg.

[Part 2- Turning a Dog](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/turning-a-dog-part-2)

[Part 3- Turning a Horse](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57144/turning-the-horse-part-3)

Comment: so you can only move one stick and the result should be that the goats head (the neck line and head line) is then on the right side?

Comment: Yes absolutely right.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Why not simply stick the sticks to a semi transclucent paper and horizontal flip the paper without moving any sticks and view from the other side?

Comment: Also we can turn the goat upside down. This would also allow the goat to look rightwards.

Comment: lateral thinking not worth an answer: the goat head is already in position if we consider left and right anterior legs

Comment: This question is epic. Made me laugh so much because of the .... 'unethical' answers? I tried finding an answer different than Newbie's but only ended up with a cocktail glass. Cheers.

Comment: Just go back to your screen and see. you see that goat's head is at right side... :)

Comment: When I first read the title in Hot Questions, I was kind of hoping this would be an RPG Stack Exchange question about a Cleric/Paladin ability.

Comment: I have a problem with the goat having 2 legs - a *left* and a *right* one :).  Shouldn't they be called *front* and *rear* legs?

Comment: As there are many, many answers to this question, I believe this question is not well-restricted enough to have a uniquely defined answer, so I've put it on hold for now as too-broad. Feel free to edit this question to significantly restrict the scope of possible answers, though, and it could be reopened.

Comment: @Emrakul It's not fair to change rules of a game during it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> Move the right most stick and place it on the bottom. This way, the goat will appear to face right when viewed with the head tilted 90 degrees to the left.

Here's the image equivalent:

> [image]

Apologies for the poor quality image. My office laptop has very limited capabilities in image editing.

Comment: Here's a [gif of this solution](http://i.imgur.com/vVsd0uP.gif) for those that are trying to visualize it.

Comment: Really brilliant, but what I wanted to know, What is the need of moving the stick ? we can directly turn(reverse) the picture as u did after moving a stick ... but you seems right http://www.learning-tree.org.uk/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5

Answer (score 55):

I've found a simpler solution that doesn't rotate the entire goat! See the image below for a visual explanation.

> 1. Separate the goat's head from its neck. 
> 2. Move the goat's head over the right leg. 
> 3. Rotate the head so it's facing the right and rest it on the goat's rump.
> Only the head has moved, and it now faces the right and is above the right leg.
> [image: reforming a goat]

Comment: I guess we have a winner

Comment: +1 Wrong in so many ways... but right in that it, technically, answers the question....

Comment: you just beheaded the goat, man now how will others try out.

Comment: That's what I call creativity! +1

Comment: @prog_SAHIL There are two more left in [this answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17248/10880)

Answer (score 27):

Move the right leg up, so it seems like it was jumping down:

> [image]
>  It's head is now on the right side, and what was its head is now a tail.

Comment: NO, this isn't the write way. You can't handicap the goat or add additional parts like tail. Modified figure should have same parts as in the question.

Comment: *"You can't handicap the goat"* PETA would be pissed.

Comment: You have not written I can't, so I consider it valid. If you see my goat, it now looks much happier and cheerful. Everyone sees it's having fun, jumping around and playing. It looks much better than sitting on the back in uncomfortable position, as in the [top answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17173/10880).

Comment: I like this; the goat is kicking and gleefully causing trouble, as a goat should. This meets the criteria of the question without requiring spurious logic.

Comment: "No this isn't the write way" #irony

Answer (score 23):

A try:

> [image]
>
>  
> the head is turned to the right

Comment: Truly brilliant.

Comment: But it doesnt fulfill the condition that the head should be above the right leg.

Comment: @Jakob Yeah, you are right.

Comment: No , Head is just not above the right leg.

Comment: @Jakob: The original goat was looking toward the viewer (head over left [fore]leg).  This one is looking away (head over right [fore]leg).

Comment: @Jakob Well, its right leg is behind the left leg (which we don't see because of 2D). Alternatively, it just has to be **above** the right leg, meaning higher than. :P

Comment: It only has two legs!

Comment: It must have four, since prog_SAHIL in the comments said that we "can't handicap the goat"! He wouldn't have done it himself, would he?

Comment: @Samthere Maybe the goat was born with two legs? Now because of its disability it would like to to see what is behind and can't, so this is the *true* reason of the question.

Comment: @Voitcus Ah, that makes sense; this is a cry for help, not a puzzle!

Comment: No, on the right are the hind legs.  The head doesn't go there.  The right legs are the front legs.  They are on the left.

Answer (score 22):

Here is my try :

> You can do it without moving any stick. Just go to the other side of the goat. The head will be on the right side, over the right leg. But since you have to move at least one stick, I moved her head in a more comfortable position so she's happier now.
> [image: Happy goat]

Comment: I want to say that this answer is wrong but... it.... it isn't...The goat is not specified to be like matchsticks on a flat surface or simular to a statue.  These answers are much better received if "laterial-thinking" is one of the tags.

Comment: SuperB Logic cadaesh Out of the Box

Answer (score 12):

This question / Puzzle tag with "geometry" So here I came with geometry answer + little funny too as I notice that there are some really (rofl) answers.
Now Here is Goat which given by @prog_SAHIL. She is look something like this.

[image]

Now here some geometry comes and now lets rotate her **leg 1** to 45* clock wise. So its look something like this..

[image]

So Now, leg 2 becomes her neck, leg 1 becomes leg 2 and neck + head become leg 1 and tail.

Just like this.

[image]

So now you are thinking that where is her head. ????

Head isn't go any where, its here. You force her to turn, you force her to seet now she is looking at you angry. So here is her head, (below Image)

[image]

Original, If she don't look at you. :P

[image]

> **AND IF ROTATION IS ALLOW, YOU DO NOT NEED TO DO ANY THING, JUST FLIP HER HORIZONTALLY AS SAME AS I DO ON FIRST IMAGE AND LAST IMAGE**

Comment: +1 for well researched answer. However, I'm looking at your photos and have a suspicion that each photo shows a different goat, which was not allowed.

Comment: @Voitcus thnx for ur commenct. However i need live goat for perform these oprations . Ha ha ha

Answer (score 12):

What about this?  A move that satisfies the criteria in a three-dimensional way.

> The right leg becomes the head of a happy goat all sprawled out, viewed from above.
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Um, okay. That works.

Comment: God, that's so good! :-D

Comment: ahaa cute baby goat :D <3

Answer (score 10):

Since rotation is allowed as per CodeNewbie's answer, I can do it without moving *any* sticks!

> [image: new goat]

Comment: That's one strange-looking goat!

Comment: @mmking Sure, but is it any stranger than the original? :-)

Answer (score 6):

My interpretation would be to pivot at the neck/back joint. Technically only one line has been moved because the back leg (now the front) is attached and simply follows the back.  It meets the requirement of being "above the right leg" although I suspect OP also wants the head to be to the right of the right leg?

[image: My interpretation]

Comment: Stay away, Sheepish! This question is meant for the goatish.

Comment: Don't try this at home

Comment: U can't move 2 sticks..AGAINST THE RULES.

Comment: Did you just break its neck?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that the neck is the only part of the body that connects the head with the body, can moving the neck towards the right side of the body, take the head to the right side too (along with the neck) ?[image]

Comment: You can only move one stick. If you move the head and the neck, you are moving two sticks.

Answer (score -2):

sorry, no picture, but I'll describe it: take the hind leg; attach it to the front foot and make it parallel to the back; now rotate the picture 90 degrees to the right. Now the goat's head is over the hind leg.

Comment: This answer has already been provided by another user. I suggest that you either remove your answer or add more information which will differentiate your answer from the previous ones.