# Turning a dog (Part 2)

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, geometry, matches

Here is Mr. Dog, friend of Mrs. Goat. Move only two matchsticks such that Mr. Dog's head faces the opposite direction, i.e. to the right side.

[image: Mr. Dog]
This is Part 2 of turning the animal series.

[See Part 1 - Turning a Goat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/turning-a-goat)

Comment: this is just as broad as your previous puzzle that was closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Like this?

[image]

Edit: Fixed head (I must write something to get 30 characters)

Comment: For some users out there, if you feel like you need to write something unnecessary in your answer so it has at least the right amount of limit of words, write `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$` and keep writing `{}` until you've reached the desired limit. This is what it produces: $${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$ Nothing :)

Answer (score 10):

How about this (apologies for the wobbly lines)

> [image]

Comment: I just was thinking about this solution, you didn't let me time to open paint D:

Comment: Incorrect, You moved three matchsticks instead of two. TRY AGAIN

Comment: he only moved two

Comment: @prog_SAHIL I moved the tail and the lower jaw.

Comment: I agree. only two were moved and the tail just happens to be down now instead of up. You didn't mention the tail in the question so this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with the cheeky answer of:

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I thought of, but I didn't want to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw all of your tentative and i raise you this :

[image: boop]