# Turning the Horse Part 3

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, geometry, matches

Here's the sequel to [Turning the Goat Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17172/turning-a-goat) and [Turning the Dog Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/turning-a-dog-part-2)

[image]

As Hobble the horse stood on the hillside staring at the hurdle below, he
wondered if he would ever have the courage and strength to jump it. He
dreamt that one day, he would be facing the hurdle from the hill on the other
side, an equal distance away. Move exactly six matches so that this is so.

Comment: I don't get why part 2 was closed. The puzzle was well designed and well in boundaries to be reported as too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work -

> [image]

Sorry, for the image artifacts. Moved the sticks using paint.

Steps

> It is made by moving 2 legs, 1 head, 1 body and the corresponding matches in the hurdle

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for very bad edit, anyone welcome to edit

original image:

> [image]

After moving six mathces:

> [image]

Hope its clear with numbers (moved matches with numbers: 2,3,6,8,10 and 11)

Comment: +1 for a better explanation